# Shopify app to create actual some thing on store

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I want to ask you if you can help me, I'm trying for hours to find some tutorial which shows how to create an shopify app which creates for example some countdown timer for the product page or something like that, on each tutorial I just found some code where you are editing the admin system of your app but not creating a features for your shopify store.

Comment: We can help you if you provide a code of what have you tried, but recommending tutorials is not the purpose of StackOVerflow so we won't be able to help you with this.

Comment: @drip I believe the purpose of stackoverflow is for **developers** to help each others on identified topics in general. Now, I'm an experienced developer and after spending hours looking up app-bridge, polaris, shopify official react/nextjs tutorial, shopify graphql api, etc... I'm literally facing the same issue as OP: I still don't have a clue on how an app should enrich shops online store. Providing some specific pointers could help.

Comment: @adrián-bortník since your post was 10 months ago, you probably found a solution somehow. hence I strongly encourage you to post an update to help other devs facing the same issue for future reference. Thanks !

Comment: @Syffys I recommend reading the guide in the Help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic You can see point 4 where this topic falls under off-topic clearly. At the moment this question sound like "my car broke down, I looked all over for the internet but couldn't find a solution, fix the car for me", while he didn't even try to open the hood of the car. A proper question should include what was tried until this point (in code) before reaching to the conclusion that help is needed. Please consider opening a new question if you are facing a specific problem. ;)

Comment: @drip this is not the place to discuss this, so we ll have to agree to disagree: we did try to open the hood of the car, but it's such a mess in there that we need some assistance finding our way. So maybe OP question could use an update, but I did state what I tried in my comment.